# Calculating IRR in Julia

Tags: julia, quantitative-finance

I can calculate NPV using

```
tvmnpv(i,cfo,cfall)=begin
n=collect(1:length(cfall));
cfo + sum(cfall./(1+i).^n)
end
```

where `cfo` is the initial cashflow at t=0, and `cfall` represents the following cashflows and `i` is the discount rate being used.

However, I can not find a way to calculate the IRR given the cashflows. I believe excel uses a function that scrolls through possible values until a value where cfo plus the discounted following cashflows equals zero is found. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

An example of desired output is as follows:

`cfo=[-100];cfall=[30,30,30,30]`

`Out: 0.07713847`

Therefore, the IRR is 7.713847%.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Calculate the [IRR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_rate_of_return) is a [Root-finding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm) problem (find `i` for NPV=0).

One way to do this calculation, is to use the [Roots.jl](https://github.com/JuliaMath/Roots.jl) package (`Pkg.add("Roots")`), as following:

```
julia> using Roots

julia> tvmnpv(i,cfo,cfall)=begin
         n=collect(1:length(cfall));
         cfo + sum(cfall./(1+i).^n)
       end
tvmnpv (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f(x)=tvmnpv(x, cfo, cfall)
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> cfo=-100.0
-100.0

julia> cfall=[30, 30, 30, 30];

julia> fzero(f, [0.0, 1.0])
0.07713847295208355
```

---

The interval `[0.0, 1.0]` could be changed for better performance.

If you don't want to install the package, I would recommend you to implement the [Bisection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method) method, which is simple and efficient.

<sub>tested with Julia Version 0.5.0</sub>

Comment: Thank you so much. I will test this once I have access to my computer again.

Answer (score 1):

The [ActuaryUtilities](https://github.com/JuliaActuary/ActuaryUtilities.jl) package provides an `internal_rate_of_return` (also aliased as`irr`) function.